# Cannot test python list element membership when element contains numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I defined a custom data structure using `namedtuple`, which contains numpy array.

```
from collections import namedtuple
import numpy as np

AA = namedtuple('AA', 'name, x')
c = []
c.append(AA('x', np.arange(3)))
c.append(AA('x', np.arange(3)))
c.append(AA('y', np.arange(3)))
c[0] in c
c[1] in c
c[2] in c
```

Strangely, the `c[1]` test fails, whereas the other two works.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-c1daf83cd082> in <module>
----> 1 c[1] in c

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use c.any() or c.all()
```

The error seems to be related to numpy arrray equality test `c[0].x == c[1].x`. But for some reason the membership test for the first element always succeeds

```
s = []
s.append(np.arange(3))
s.append(np.arange(3))
s[0] in s
s[1] in s
```

Also see this example

```
class A:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        raise ValueError
        
a = [A(), A()]
a[0] in a
a[1] in a
```

Also I don't know why `c[2] in c` returns `True`.

Comment: `c[0] in c` This asks "Is the first element of c a member of c?", which is obviously true.  What is the purpose here?

Comment: @JohnGordon  And `c[1] in c` asks the same question about the second element, and it fails.  That's the question.  Oddly, if you add a duplicate of the 3rd element, then it fails for items 1 and 3, but not 0 and 2.  I need to think about this one.

Comment: Numpy `eq` might check for `id`, `data`, `shape` before comparing the elements. Therefore `c[1] in c` fails, same goes for `s[1] in s`, and `np.arange(3) in s`, since in this case, the comparison degrades to element-wise comparison.

Comment: OK, it only fails in those cases where it has to check the array.  If the "name" elements are different, then it doesn't have to check the array.

Comment: And for what it's worth, the same thing happens with an ordinary (unnamed) tuple.

Comment: Regarding tuples, `c = [(1,2,3), (1,2,3), (4,5,6)]; c[1] in c` works fine. The point is, numpy arrays are mutable, and should not be used in `some_array in something`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplified:

```
def my_in(obj, container):
    for elem in container:
        if bool(my_compare_equal(obj, elem)):
            return True
    return False

def my_compare_equal(obj, elem):
    if id(obj) == id(elem):
        return True
    return obj.__eq__(elem)
```

For more datails, see **[list_contains](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/52cd6d5e1b2bece0d8efb58b1af41071c914ebe6/Objects/listobject.c#L423)** and then **[PyObject_RichCompareBool](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7244c0060dc3ef909f34b0791c3e7490b0340d5e/Objects/object.c#L751)**, **[PyObject_RichCompare](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7244c0060dc3ef909f34b0791c3e7490b0340d5e/Objects/object.c#L729)**, **[do_richcompare](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7244c0060dc3ef909f34b0791c3e7490b0340d5e/Objects/object.c#L677)**

"Pseudo-execution" steps:

```
c = [AA('x', np.arange(3)),
     AA('x', np.arange(3)),
     AA('y', np.arange(3))]

c[0] in c
# explain:
my_in(obj=c[0], container=c)
    # for loop:
    
    # 0-iteration:
    # elem = c[0]
    my_compare_equal(obj=c[0], elem=c[0])
        # (id(c[0]) == id(c[0])) == True
        # --> True
    bool(True)
        # True.__bool__()
        # --> True
    # --> True

c[1] in c
# explain:
my_in(obj=c[1], container=c)
    # for loop:

    # 0-iteration:
    # elem = c[0]
    my_compare_equal(obj=c[1], elem=c[0])
        # (id(c[1]) == id(c[0])) == False
        # c[1].__eq__(c[0])
            # compare tuples element by element:
            # 0-iteration:
            my_compare_equal('x', 'x') == True
            # 1-iteration:
            my_compare_equal(np.arange(3), np.arange(3))
                # (id(np.arange(3)) == id(np.arange(3))) == False
                # np.arange(3).__eq__(np.arange(3))
                # --> np.ndarray([True, True, True])
            bool(np.ndarray([True, True, True]))
                # np.ndarray([True, True, True]).__bool__()
                    raise ValueError("The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()")

c[2] in c
# explain:
my_in(obj=c[2], container=c)
    # for loop:

    # 0-iteration:
    # elem = c[0]
    my_compare_equal(obj=c[2], elem=c[0])
        # (id(c[2]) == id(c[0])) == False
        # c[2].__eq__(c[0])
            # compare tuples element by element:
            # 0-iteration:
            my_compare_equal('y', 'x') == False
            # --> False
        # --> False

    # 1-iteration:
    # analogiusly as 0-iteration:
    my_compare_equal(obj=c[2], elem=c[1])
        # --> False
    
    # 2-iteration:
    my_compare_equal(obj=c[2], elem=c[2])
        # (id(c[2]) == id(c[2])) == True
        # --> True
    # --> True
```

Comment: A sentence of prose explaining the code would improve this answer a lot. I get what you're demonstrating, but you don't actually *say* it in a way that somebody who doesn't know what you're doing (and doesn't want to read C source code) can follow.

Comment: Added pseudo-execution steps